# How to replace brackets by using regex

Tags: python, string

I have written a calculator for solving quadratic equations, using cmath.

So far I've successfully replaced 'j' into 'i' in the results, but failed to find a way to replace the brackets and the "0i" (if exist).

```
import cmath
a_2 = float(input('a: '))
b_1 = float(input('b: '))
c_0 = float(input('c: '))
delta = (b_1**2) - (4*a_2*c_0)
sol1 = (-b_1-cmath.sqrt(delta))/(2*a_2)
sol2 = (-b_1+cmath.sqrt(delta))/(2*a_2)
sol1i = re.sub(r'j', 'i', str(sol1))
sol2i = re.sub(r'j', 'i', str(sol2))
print(f'x_1={sol1i},x_2={sol2i}')
```

Result:

```
a: 1
b: 2
c: 1
x_1=(-1+0i),x_2=(-1+0i)
```

What I want:

```
a: 1
b: 2
c: 1
x_1=-1,x_2=-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `str.replace()` or `str.strip()`. It will be much simpler and intuitive than using regex. (Same thing applies to your replacing `j` with `i`)

```py
>>> sol1i.strip(")(")
'-1+0i'
>>> # or this option
>>> sol1i.replace(")", "").replace("(", "")
'-1+0i
```

---

UPD: even simpler it would be like this

```py
>>> f"x_1={sol1.real:g} + {sol1.imag:g}i,x_2={sol2.real:g} + {sol2.imag:g}i"
x_1=-1 + 0i,x_2=-1 + 0i
```

UPD2: now I've noticed the option of omitting zero imaginary unit in print.

```py
sol1 = (-b_1-cmath.sqrt(delta))/(2*a_2)
sol2 = (-b_1+cmath.sqrt(delta))/(2*a_2)
print(f"x_1={sol1.real:g}" + (f" + {sol1.imag:g}i" if sol1.imag else ""), end=",")
print(f"x_2={sol2.real:g}" + (f" + {sol2.imag:g}i" if sol2.imag else ""))
```

Comment: I haven't thought of using 'real' and 'imag'. This is inspiring.
One more question, how does 'g' in the 'sol1.real:g' work? Is it a inner function or a regex?

Comment: @ThomasPeng this is format for float numbers. You can remove it and then there will be trailing zero(s), so this option formats value from let's say 1.0 to 1, so it looks like int. There is a [spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: @ThomasPeng you basically only need to know something like this exists and not remember by heart. When I was playing with my solution, I had an idea it would be nice to not include trailing zeros, but I didn't remember the correct formatter, so googled it and included in my answer.
As for regexes, I'd recommend you to focus on simplicity, regexes are commonly overused. :) Which doesn't mean to not use them at all, but try to use them when it's really relevant.